# Show element in Chrome elements tab by js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
window.chrome.focus(myElement);
```

Is there any api like this to show a certain element in Chrome's elements tab? I have a full-page cover layer that make me can't focus a element by click it and I must to trace the html tree to focus it in elements tab, that's very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an element in the JavaScript console with `document.querySelector` and then right click on the result > `Reveal in Elements panel`.

Comment: Yeah, and more I can `console.log(myel)` and focus it in console. Good idea.